# why main method in c# is always placed inside the class but not in c++

Tags: c#, c++, oop, program-entry-point

Why we put `main()` method always inside the `class` in C# while in c++ it always placed outside of the `class`.

Comment: None of the answers have added any historical context...  So many programming languages most of them have an entry point called `main` why `main` and not say `start` ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar `start` would have worked too. But there had to be a choice made. Once a choice was made then that choice stuck.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: In fact, it was called `start` in BCPL, but became `main` in B (a precursor to C, based on BCPL), perhaps as part of a general trend towards terseness. Memory was expensive in the sixties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For historical reasons.  C++ evolved from C, which had a global `main()` function.  C# is much younger and was designed from scratch.  One of the design features of C# is the absence of global functions, so the `main` function has to belong to a class.

Comment: I don't think this is historical. If the decision were to be made today I think it would still be made into a free-standing function. Unlike some languages C++ fully embraces global functions.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: It _is_ historical, but the non-historical reasoning does indeed hold a proper amount of weight :)

Answer (score 12):

The C++ language designers followed the lead of C and so the main function is a plain function.

The C# language designers made the choice, when designing the language, that all methods must be part of classes.

Answer (score 4):

Because in .NET you can place methods only inside types. You cannot have them floating around in the empty space. C++ has its legacy from C which is not an OOP language so you could define functions anywhere.

Comment: It's not just legacy; freestanding functions are very useful and the C++ standard introduces a lot of them beyond those inherited from C.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot place method outside class/struct in C#. Each method must be in class/struct

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention. Which is in line with Java (also follows the semantic of having a method inside class).

Comment: i know but is there any other specific reason or just a convention?

Comment: @r_ohit - It is just a convention. Java's designers thought it was a good idea to have everything more OO. Then they invented static functions to overcome the limitation...

Comment: It's not a convention - it's a requirement of the language. A convention implies that there are other possibilities.

Comment: @BoPersson: "Java's designers [...] invented static functions" -> static members existed in OO languages way before Java appeared. For instance, they were introduced in C++ in 1991.

Comment: @adelphus - The other alternative obviously was to design the language otherwise.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

C# is complete object oriented language where everything is considered as objects. Hence, Main() is kept inside class.