# Why don't we place the C++ main method inside a class?

Tags: c++

In C++ why don't we ever place the main method inside a class (like Java)? Why doesn't doing so make sense (I think)?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002790/why-main-method-in-c-sharp-is-always-placed-inside-the-class-but-not-in-c

Comment: simply because this is not java

Comment: Why on Earth would we do that? C++ actually has functions and real namespaces, you know.

Comment: Thanks guys! Now I understand this. And, thanks for the link, @NKamrath !!

Comment: Why don't horses have stripes? Zebras have them

Comment: Just to clarify: I wasn't trying to be snarky or anything. Was just trying to get the point across as bluntly as possible. :)

Comment: Because classes discriminate against egoistic functions that consider themselves main.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We can. `main` is not a reserved word. But by the language standard, the C++ toolchain expects the entry point of the program to be `main` in the global scope. So the `main` inside a class won't be recognized as the program's entry point.

Feel free to define a class method called `main`, and call it from the global `main`.

This design comes all the way from C. Compatibility with existing C code was a major design goal of C++ early on, and there was hardly any real benefit to changing the entry point convention. So they kept the C standard in place. And like everyone said, C++, unlike Java, does perfectly allow for standalone (i. e. non-class) functions.

Comment: It's not so much that the linker expects it as that the language standard demands it.

Comment: The language standard is being enforced by the linker in this case - assuming you link an executable. The compiler is perfectly happy to compile code without main().

Comment: @Mark B: here at SO, we say thanks by upvoting or accepting the answer :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: "what the language standard says", and "what the linker you're currently using happens to accept" are two different things, and it's rarely a good idea to mix them up. The linker will happily link code with or without a `main` function in the global scope, but that doesn't change what the language standard has to say about the `main` function and the program's entry point.

Comment: It's not the linker that enforce a main function. The linker uses a set of runtime modules like crt0.o, crtn.o etc. These modules usually require the function with the name `main`. But you can change these modules what might make sense especially in embedded environment. -- But it's ugly to use a C++ decorated name in the crtX modules. So usually we use just `main`.

Comment: Re "Compatibility with existing C code was a major design goal of C++ early on": actually, this is probably more a result of the fact that CFRONT, the original C++ compiler, was little more than a C++-to-C translator, meaning it had all the infrastructure of C baked in.

Answer (score 23):

Why would we? Why do we need to?

For a class method to make sense, we have to have an instance of an object. When `main` is called, we don't have an instance.

So it *could* have been made a static member function instead, but *what would be the point*? Is it "more object-oriented"? How so?

I think it makes good sense the way C++ does it: `main` is where you start *before* you have any objects, before any instances exist.

In Java, `main` is a static member because nothing else exists. But in C++, non-member functions exist, so why not let `main` be one of those?

Comment: I like this answer best, but I feel I can't upvote, because not only can you have lots of objects before `main` executes, the standard dictates there are some objects which _must_ exist before `main`.  (`cin`)

Comment: That's not how the historical thinking behind the standard went. `main` (in C) predates the very notion of classes. In C++, they wanted compatibility with C.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I never said this was the historical reasoning. But if there had been a strong argument in favor of making it a class member, then C++ *could* have done it and sacrificed C compatibility. But there wasn't. It wouldn't really have offered any advantages, and it would have broken C compatibility

Comment: @MooingDuck: fair enough. I was thinking of user-created objects. Sure, it could have been a member of some system-created instance, a global object defined by the standard library just like it defines `cin`. But Java and C# don't do that: they make it a static member of a user-defined class.

Comment: @Jalf: All globals are initialized before `main` too.  Those are user-created objects.  I know about Java and C#, I'm merely saying that one sentence of your answer is wrong.

Comment: Yup, but if you go that route, than `main` is no longer your entry point. Instead, your program just consists of whatever functions are invoked by the construction of the globals you define.

Answer (score 10):

Because in C which far predates classes, `main` was a standalone function and that wasn't changed in C++ to maintain compatibility.

If you really want to do this, there's nothing stopping you from writing a class you instantiate in `main` and then call a `main` method upon.

Answer (score 7):

C++ does not have the requirement, found in C# and Java, that every piece of code belong to a class of some description. C++ allows for standalone functions amd `main` falls into that category.

Hence `main` belongs to *no* class.

Of course, you can *create* a class that contains a `main` function, but that won't be *the* main function that gets called automagically on program start:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() {
        std::cout << "In SomeClass constructor\n";
    }
    ~SomeClass() {
        std::cout << "In SomeClass destructor\n";
    }
    static int main() {
        std::cout << "In SomeClass main\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "In real main\n";
    { SomeClass xyzzy; } // Just to ensure destructor called before main exit.
    std::cout << "Exit real main\n";
}
```

The output of that shows that the class variant of `main` is not called:

```
In real main
In SomeClass constructor
In SomeClass destructor
Exit real main
```

Answer (score 3):

C++ was intended and is supposed to be backward compatible with C and cfront 
(the first C++ compiler) wouldn't have worked if main had not been allowed.

The first / original C++ compiler, called cfront, compiled C++ by converting
it to C, and the C language requires the use of main()

See the following URL's for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront

http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/

Answer (score 2):

In C++, main() is a function that is called when the program runs, and is not a method. This main function may use classes and methods of classes in its execution.

Methods are functions defined within classes that are intended to stay close to the class/object they are defined in. Therefore, main() is not stuck inside a class because it is not meant to act upon a single class or object

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake (method->function). Thanks for explaining!!

Answer (score 1):

main has nothing to do with classes in C++. It's a reserved function name that the linker knows that is the entrypoint (address) of the application

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

Answer (score 0):

As cpp is evolved from core c, the definition, declaration and invoking the function follows same process in both the languages...as cpp is object oriented, we can play classes and objects game with it..but as in c, we cannot add main method inside any user derived function or we can say main method should be isolated from functions.. likewise in cpp we cannot add main method inside any class , it should be isolated... there in no any concept like driver class in cpp...in java, yes! We can add main method inside the class or we have to add main in class in java we can say!!