# Undefined reference to main when adding a slider for axes

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm currently trying to add sliders to move across different axes in OpenGl/QT/C++ but get a vague 'undefined reference to `main'' error when compiling. Here is my main class...

My header file:

```
#include "MyWidget.h"
#ifndef MYMAIN_H
#define MYMAIN_H

class MyMain: public QObject{

    public:
    MyMain();
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
    MyWidget *MyWidget;

    public slots:
    void setXTranslation(int value);
};

#endif
```

My source file:

```
#include "MyMain.h"

 MyMain::MyMain()
 {
 }

 int MyMain::main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     some code here...


     QSlider *xSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
     xSlider->setRange(0, 10);

     QObject::connect(xSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 this, SLOT(setXTranslation(int)));


     some more code here.... 

     // start it running
     return app.exec();
 }
 void MyMain::setXTranslation(int value)
 {
     some more code here....
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A program shall contain a global function called main.

You may implement your main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     return MyMain().main(argc, argv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int MyMain::main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ^^^^^^^^
```

delete this.

The `main` function needs to be in the global scope, not in `MyMain`.

Comment: If I want to call setXTranslation() in the main via signals and slots doesn't the main need to be defined in the header file though?

Answer (score 1):

C++ language expects the `main()` function to be in global scope (Though it is not a keyword) and recognizes it as an entry point to the program.

If `main()` is defined inside a class as `MyMain::main()` in your case, it is not considered / recognized as an entry point by the compiler.

similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420531/3901817/).